# Can i download GTA V and play the same game at other computer at the same time?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

The question is that Can i download GTA V and play the same game at other computer at the same time? Will my download stop or no?

Comment: It shouldn't...

Comment: Have you tried? I think Steam stops a download when you start another game, but you can manualy resume it. Also, if the game itself is downloading an update, that Steam doesn't stop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. You can log in on both devices and play games on one while you download on the other (as long as you aren't simultaneously playing games on both).

Bear in mind that if both devices are on the same network, the download may cause connectivity issues with an online game you play at the same time, such as lag.